# SSIS Sequence Container -transaction level

Tags: transactions, aggregate-functions, ssis

I have a sequence container and have defined DFD's inside the container.

From the source system,I am taking a dataset based on some criteria.
.
I need to find the maximum of an Id based on the result set.

For that I used Aggregate transformation editor and is taking lot of memory while getting the result(when processing tables with millions of data rows.)

My constraint is like ,I cant change the query(to select the max datetime from query itself).

Other soluton will be like using a execute SQL Task to get the latest datetime (within the DFD executable).

Will that cause data inconsistency problems(suppose a new row with max id gets inserted when I use execute SQL task?).[Data mismatch between selected dataset max date and execute SQL maxdate?)

Or my understanding about the transaction level of Sequence Container is wrong?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a SQL query to find the maximum - why use these tasks?  Your problems though...maybe I don't want to understand ;)

> My constraint is like ,I cant change
>   the query(to select the max datetime
>   from query itself).
>
> Other soluton will be like using a
>   execute SQL Task to get the latest
>   datetime (within the DFD executable).

So you can't change your query, but you can create a new one?  If you put those two tasks in a transaction container and set it correctly, transactions will take effect and stop an insert from happening until after you are done.

Comment: Ya :) we all work with some constraints rite ...Sam what you mean by a transaction container here?

Comment: Sam, Can I use two selects(One for selecting ) and one select to select max date and ensure that both will be in sync.(I read from MS forums like:order of execution of components at same level depends on the execution engine).So I was a bit concerned about using the execute SQL task to get the max date with in the DFD.And my DFD's are inside a sequence container(Is that what you meant by transaction container?)

Comment: I should have said sequence container.

Comment: If you put those two tasks in a transaction container and set it correctly, transactions will take effect and stop an insert from happening until after you are done. Chris...can you elaborate on this..Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help - http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server